Elliptic integral singular expansion
The question. Consider the Elliptic Integral
$$
F(x;k)=\int_0^x \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}}.\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
I am interested in the singular series expansion of $F(1;k)$ about $k=1$. I was told it should be of the form
$$
F(1;k)=C\log(|k-1|)+{\text{analytic expansion in $k$}},
$$
where $C$ is some constant. Would anyone have a reference explaining HOW such an expansion is obtained and how can one compute the various coefficients of the expansion?
The reasons why I am interested in this problem is made clear in this question, which involves an integral that has a similar singular behavior as \eqref{1} has about $k=1$. Indeed, if I extend the divergent integral in here as
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\cos(x)+1+a)(\cos(x)+1+b)}},\tag{2}\label{2}
$$
for some $a,b>0$, then the integral above is divergent as $b\to 0$.
If I can understand how the expansion of \eqref{1} (a well-known integral) is obtained, I can certainly understand how to do the same for the integral \eqref{2} as $b\to 0$.

Using Mathematica notations,
$$\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}=F\left(\sin ^{-1}(t)|k^2\right)$$
$$f(1;k)=K\left(k^2\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\, a_n\,(k-1)^n$$ where the first "coefficients" are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & \frac{1}{2} (\log (1-k)-3 \log (2)) \\
 1 & \frac{1}{4} (\log (1-k)-3 \log (2))+1 \\
 2 & \frac{1}{32} (5 \log (1-k)-15 \log (2))+7 \\
 3 & \frac{1}{192} (21 \log (1-k)-63 \log (2))+34    \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Would it be possible to tell me how these expansions are obtained? That's because I want to obtain the expansion for (2).
